# Correct MX records to use for Google Apps?

Tags: mx-record, g-suite

Ive just migrated quite a few sites to new server. In doing this i also have done a audit of the DNS setup of all our domains.

Several domains use Google Apps for their email and i noticed a couple of discrepancies in the MX records they used (please see full list of MX records below). Domain L, starts with `0 - APSMX`, where as the others start with `10 - ASPMX`. Non of them are identical after the first record either.

Are any of these right / wrong ?

Could there be an issue with mail not getting through due to the way they are configured ?

**Domain L**

```
0 - ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
5 - ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
5 - ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
10 - ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
10 - ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
```

**Domain PP**

```
10 - ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
20 - ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
20 - ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
30 - ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
30 - ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
```

**Domain P**

```
10 - ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
20 - ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
20 - ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
30 - ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
30 - ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
```

Answer (score 4):

As stated by google support the following settings should be used (or, they are recommended).
aspmx.l.google.com is the main server and should have top priority (1).

```
Priority    Mail Server
1           ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5           ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5           ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10          ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10          ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

Source: https://support.google.com/a/answer/33915?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, do you know if i change them, to the ones in the above link is there a danger of losing any email while they proppergate over ?

Comment: Unlikely that anything will get lost.